# RegEx for comma seperated list

Tags: regex, validation

I want to validate a list of values seperated by commas, without a comma after the last value:

Shoud be valid:

> altdns1.at, altdns2.de.fr, altdns3.de

Should be invalid:

> altdns1.at, altdns2.de.fr, altdns3.de,

My RegEx:

```
^([^,]+,)*([^,]*)$
```

My thoughts:

- `([^,]+,)`   beginning of string: any character except comma - one to unlimited times - followed by a comma
- `*` all this zero to unlimited times
- `([^,]*)`  end of string: any character except comma - one to unlimited times

Regex101 shows this string matches my pattern:

> altdns1.de.de,altdns2.de.de,altdns3.de.de,

Why?

Comment: Your last quantifier is `*`, not `+`; `end of string: any character except comma - one to unlimited times` is false, it's actually zero to unlimited times

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
^[^,]+(?:,[^,]+)*$
```

**Explanation:**

```
^           : begining of line
  [^,]+     : 1 or more not comma
  (?:       : start non capturing group
    ,       : a comma
    [^,]+   :  1 or more not comma
  )*        : end group, may appear 0 or more times
$           : end of line
```